# How to get parent ConstraintLayout view to match its child TextView height programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

It's awesome to be learning ConstraintLayout and Kotlin. I have a constraintLayout popupView, which is the parent view of a TextView titleLabel. I'd like popupView height to adjust to the content of its child titleLabel TextView. titleLabel height can vary due to different text strings used.

Both titleLabel and popupView are set to WRAP_CONTENT for the height layout params, but the popupView isn't getting rendered. Adding a fixed height constraint to popupView's constraintSet will render it, but a fixed height will not work when titleLabel height changes.

Any ideas how to get it working? Here's what I have

```
open class PopupActivity(): AppCompatActivity() {

  public var message:String = "This is a message string for the label"

  val titleLabel: TextView by lazy {
    val label = TextView(this)
    label.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    label.setTextSize(Constants.FontSizePopupTitle)
    return@lazy label
  }

  val popupView: ConstraintLayout by lazy {
    val view = ConstraintLayout(this)
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.primary())
    return@lazy view
  }

  val view: ConstraintLayout by lazy {
    val v = ConstraintLayout(this)
    return@lazy v
  }

  @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    view.id = 1
    popupView.id = 2
    titleLabel.id = 5

    var margin = 2 * Constants.SpacingStandard.toInt()

    view.addView(popupView)
    popupView.addView(titleLabel)

    titleLabel.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
      ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT,
      ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    titleLabel.text = message


    popupView.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
      ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT,
      ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    val popupConstraintSet = ConstraintSet()

    popupConstraintSet.connect(popupView.id, START, view.id, START, margin)
    popupConstraintSet.connect(popupView.id, END, view.id, END, margin)
    popupConstraintSet.centerHorizontally(popupView.id, view.id)
    popupConstraintSet.centerVertically(popupView.id, view.id)

    view.setConstraintSet(popupConstraintSet)
    setContentView(view)
  }
}
```

Comment: aren't you missing TOP and BOTTOM constraints of the view?

Comment: perhaps, though i had added a constraintSet to popupView, which connected titleLabel and popupView top,bottom,start,end but it also didn't render. not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by switching the order of the view#id in the connect functions

```
popupConstraintSet.connect(view.id, START, popupView.id, START, margin)
popupConstraintSet.connect(view.id, END, popupView.id, END, margin)
popupConstraintSet.centerHorizontally(view.id, popupView.id)
popupConstraintSet.centerVertically(view.id, popupView.id)
```

OR set the ConstraintSet to the popUpView. The field already has the correct name ^^

```
popUpView.setConstraintSet(popupConstraintSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

- remove popupView.layoutParams; WRAP_CONTENT for height seems to be ignored...
- add constrainHeight with WRAP_CONTENT to constraintSet

onCreate is now this:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    view.id = 1
    popupView.id = 2
    titleLabel.id = 5

    popupView.addView(titleLabel)
    view.addView(popupView)

    titleLabel.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
      ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT,
      ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    titleLabel.text = message


    var margin = 2 * Constants.SpacingStandard.toInt()
    val popupConstraintSet = ConstraintSet()

    popupConstraintSet.connect(popupView.id, START, view.id, START, margin)
    popupConstraintSet.connect(popupView.id, END, view.id, END, margin)
    popupConstraintSet.constrainHeight(popupView.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
    popupConstraintSet.centerHorizontally(popupView.id, view.id)
    popupConstraintSet.centerVertically(popupView.id, view.id)

    view.setConstraintSet(popupConstraintSet)

    setContentView(view)
  }
}
```